# React hooks one checkbox checked to uncheck other checkbox

Tags: react-hooks

Hi I have a parent component which contains a bunch child components which are checkboxes.
parent component is something like this inside:

```
const [items, setItems] = useState([
{
    id:1,
    selected: false,
},
{
    id:2,
    selected: false,
}
]);
const changeSelected = (id) =>
  {
    items.forEach((item)=>
    {
      if (item.id === id)
      {
        item.selected = !item.selected;
      }
      else{
        item.selected = false;
      }
    })
  }
return(
    <div>
        {items.map((item)=>{
            <Child item={item} changeSelected={changeSelected}/>
        })}
    </div>
)
```

and in the child component, it has something like this inside:

```
return(
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" checked={props.item.selected} onChange={()=>{props.changeSelected(props.item.id)}} />
    </div>
)
```

I know partially this isnt working is because useState is async but I dont know what to do to make it work, or if I should try a different approach? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You are not updating the state anywhere. You should make a copy of the array and then change the object you want to:

```
const changeSelected = (id) =>
  { let newItems = [];
    items.forEach((item)=>
    {
      if (item.id === id)
      {
        newItems.push({  id : item.id , selected : item.selected });
      }
      else{
        newItems.push({  id : item.id , selected : false });
      }
    })
setItems(newItems);
  }
```

Call setItems to set it.

**Note:**
Not related to the question but you should use unique keys when iterating over list.

```
{items.map((item)=>{
            <Child key={item.id} item={item} changeSelected={changeSelected}/>
        })}
```

Comment: I tried it but it gives me a warning: Encountered two children with the same key, `1`. Keys should be unique so that components maintain their identity across updates. Non-unique keys may cause children to be duplicated and/or omitted — the behavior is unsupported and could change in a future version

Comment: You should use a `key`. I have updated the answer. Please limit one post to one question and google before asking

Comment: I did use id as unique key, I just did not put it here. I did not have the warning before I tried your solution

Comment: My bad i have updated the answer. As you can see we were passing the same id everytime. fixed that

Answer (score 0):

You can refactor your function to this:

```
const changeSelected = (id) => {
  setItems(prev => ([...prev, {id, selected: !prev.filter(x => x.id === id)[0].selected}]))
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Obviously I forgot to setItem according to the two answers I received. But I think the right way to do it is to make a deep copy of my existing `items`, and setItems again. For my future reference, here is what I have now working (an example):

```
let newItems = [...items];
      newItems.forEach((item)=>
      {
        if (item.id === id)
        {
          item.selected = !item.selected;
        }
        else{
          item.selected = false;
        }
      })
    setProducts(newItems);
```